# How do i export Python File and the Text File Variable?

Tags: python, automation, bots

I just made my first python bot. Its an IG spambot and the code is

```
import pyautogui, time
time.sleep(5)

f = open("variable",'r')
for word in f:
    pyautogui.typewrite(word)
    pyautogui.press("enter")
```

The code contains two files , One is pasted above and second is a text file
(Named Variable here) which can be edited and spammed using the first code.
Now, if i save my project it gets combined to one as *filename.py* but i want something like i can edit the *Textfile* and spam whatever text i want to. If i run *filename.py* it will spam the variable i made in Pycharm and i have to go back to the IDE and change the variable and then again save it and run it.**strong text**

It'd be great if you can help me with this problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create another file with the words you want to write.

spammer.py

```
import pyautogui, time
time.sleep(5)

f = open("spammer.txt",'r')
for word in f:
    pyautogui.typewrite(word)
    pyautogui.press("enter")
```

spammer.txt

```
alpha
bravo
charlie
delta
echo
```

Comment: Please accept an answer so this post is removed from the "No Answer" list. Thanks.